# Need help making docky work like mac dock with minimized windows

Tags: 12.04, docky

When I minimize windows with docky it looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Ywt.png
but I want it to look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NNrh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall docky and install cairo-dock (gl-dock), then you have what you want.